# Scrapy reading urls as char values? (ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h)

Tags: python, scrapy, python-3.6

i am trying to get scrapy to download images from a table on a wikia site but it keeps giving me "ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h" when i run the project through command line.

**zhimagespider.py**

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from zh.pipelines import ZhImagesPipeline
from zh.items import ImageItem

from utils import get_raw_image

class ZhImageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zh'
    allowed_domains = ['https://zh.battlegirl.wikia.com',
                       'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/']
    start_urls = ['https://zh.battlegirl.wikia.com/wiki/%E5%8D%A1%E7%89%87%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%BD']

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath("//tr")[2:]:
            # Initialize dictionary
            item = ImageItem()

            item['image_id'] = row.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()

            # Get icons
            icons = row.css('td:nth-child(2)').xpath('.//@src').extract()
            for icon in icons:
                if icon.startswith('d'): # Or 'data'
                    icons.remove(icon)

            item['image_urls'] = get_raw_image(icons[0])

            yield item
```

**sample of traceback**

> 2017-10-28 22:48:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'image_id': '1',
>    'image_urls': 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/battlegirl/images/8/86/Card_10011_s.png/revision/latest?cb=20160212023217&path-prefix=zh'}
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
>       current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\media.py", line 79, in process_item
>       requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 152, in get_media_requests
>       return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.images_urls_field, [])]
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 152, in 
>       return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.images_urls_field, [])]
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request__init__.py", line 25, in **init**
>       self._set_url(url)
>
> File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request__init__.py", line 58, in _set_url
>       raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
>
> ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

here are the other scripts in the project:

**items.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy

class ImageItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_id = scrapy.Field()
```

**pipelines.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class ZhImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

**utils.py** is just a script that removes the part of the image url that resizes the icon on the wikia:

```
def get_raw_image(url):

    splitted = url.split('?')
    if len(splitted) == 2:
        return "?".join(["/".join(splitted[0].split("/")[0:-2])] + 
        [splitted[1]])
    elif len(splitted) == 1:
        return url
    else:
        raise ValueError('Not a resized Vignette image url: %s' %url)
```

it seems that the script is reading the urls as char values, but i'm not sure why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item['image_urls']` need to be `list` as per documentation, while in your case, you store it as a string. That's why when you loop over it in your pipeline, you loop over individual characters, starting with letter `h`. That's what `image_url` contains when you yield new `Request` and hence the error.

Comment: thank you, but how exactly would i fix it then? sorry, i'm still learning a lot and i've looked at various other examples and i can't figure out what's different with the way i'm initializing everything.

Comment: nevermind, i've got it. had to add `temp_url = get_raw_image(icons[0])`
`final_url = temp_url.split()`
`item['image_urls'] = final_url` thank you!